# Create an array of linked lists in C based on a given struct

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list

I need to complete this code by creating an array of linked lists in C.

For example:

```
list array [10]; /* or something like that... */
```

I'm ready to provide more details if needed.

This is my code for the data structure:

```
struct node;
typedef struct node *ptr;
typedef ptr list;
typedef ptr postion;

struct node {
    ptr next;
    float factor;
};

/* method for creating nodes */

int main()
{
    /* initialize array of linked lists */
}
```

Comment: Why do you specify this typedef: `typedef ptr postion;`

Comment: Are you sure you want to create ***an array*** containing linked lists or do you just want to create ***one*** linked list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your data structure:

```
struct node {
    int factor;
    struct node *next;
};
```

To create a new node in the linked list, call this function and pass the data `float factor` and the next element in the linked list `struct node *next`. The function returns the new node.

### Create a new node

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* create new node */
struct node *new_node(float factor, struct node *next)
{
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    if (!new) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->factor = factor;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}
```

### Initialize (array of) linked lists

The function `new_node` can be called like this:

```
/* first element in linked list */
struct node *head;
head = new_node(5.2, NULL);

/* add node to beginning of linked list */
head = new_node(3.7, head);
```

You can create an array of linked lists like this. Each element of the array contains the head of a linked list.

```
struct node lists[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    lists[i] = new_node((float) i, NULL);
```

### Print linked list

If you want to print all nodes contained in a linked list, call this function `print_nodes` and pass the first node of the linked list.

```
/* print the data contained in each node */
void print_nodes(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *cursor = head;
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        printf("%f ", cursor->factor);
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

### Deallocate memory

Remember to deallocate memory before exiting the program. You only need to pass the first element of the linked list to the function `free_nodes`.

```
/* free each node in linked list */
void free_nodes(struct node *head)
{
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

To free all the nodes of each linked list in the array, you would do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    free_nodes(lists[i]);
```